# Why is infix const required for arrays of strings?

Tags: arrays, constants, zig

I am learning zig slowly, but I don't understand const and how it interacts with arrays/types - I'm going through https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.6.0/#Introduction  but they use const a lot for strings.

This compiles:

```
var n  = [_][]const u8 {"test 1", "test4", "test   6", "zz"};
```

Without the `const` is an error:

```
var n  = [_][] u8 {"test 1", "test4", "test   6", "zz"};

error: expected type '[]u8', found '*const [6:0]u8'
```

similarly, putting const on the left is the same error:

```
const n  = [_][]u8 {"test 1", "test4", "test   6", "zz"};
```

What is putting the const keyword in the middle that way actually directing the compiler to do?

Comment: String literals in zig are constant, unlike C where you can assign a string to a char * pointer, then change the contents of the string. `var` is deducing the type from your description, but the array description must match the array literal, and that means `const` strings. Putting `const` on the left just means you're not going to change `n`, but it's still describing an array of non-const items, and assigning an array of const strings.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Zig, `const` applies to the next thing in the declaration.

So `[_][] u8` is an array of `u8` slices, while `[_][] const u8` is an array of slices of `const u8`. Your string literals are `*const [_:0]u8` (pointer to null-terminated array of u8; that's where the `*const [6:0] u8` in your error message is from), which Zig can coerce to slices of `const u8`.

Some examples and how mutable they are:

`[_][]u8` - Everything is mutable.

```
var move: [3][]u8 = undefined;
var ziga: [4]u8 = [_]u8{ 'z', 'i', 'g', 's' };
const zigs: []u8 = ziga[0..];
move[0] = zigs;
move[0][1] = 'a';
```

`[_][] const u8` - The slice is mutable, but things in it are not.

```
var belong_to_us = [_][]const u8{ "all", "your", "base", "are" };
var bomb = [_][]const u8{ "someone", "set", "up", "us" };
belong_to_us = bomb;
```

but

```
bomb[0][0] = 'x'; // error: cannot assign to constant
```

`const [_][] const u8` - The whole thing is immutable.

```
const signal: [3][]const u8 = [_][]const u8{ "we", "get", "signal" };
const go: [3][]const u8 = [_][]const u8{ "move", "every", "zig" };
signal = go; // error: cannot assign to constant
```

However,

`const [_][]u8` - This is a const array of slices of u8.

```
var what: [4]u8 = [_]u8{ 'w', 'h', 'a', 't' };
const signal: [3][]u8 = [_][]u8{ zigs, what[0..], zigs };
signal[0][1] = 'f'; // Legal!
signal[1] = zigs; // error: cannot assign to constant
```

That last one is a constant array of slices of mutable `u8`.

Comment: Could you also add an explanation of what a `*const [6:0]u8` is, since that is what the compiler found?

Comment: Upvoted partially for the answer, partially for the Zero Wing reference =D

Comment: @NealFultz Updated.